# Combine LINQ result from multiple DbContext into single Object

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext

I have 2 LINQ, each with different DbContext. I want to add the result of both into single object reference. that is peopleEntity and WebSyncDetailObject (reference to linq select new{..})

### Class Object

```
public class WebSyncDetailEntity
{
    public Web_SyncMatchesEntity WebSyncMatch { get; set; }

    public Web_LookupsEntity WebLookups { get; set; }

    public List<PeopleEntity> People { get; set; }
}
```

### LINQ Processing class

```
 private List<WebSyncDetailEntity> ProcessGetWebSyncDetail()
    {
        List<WebSyncDetailEntity> WebSyncDetailObject = null;

        using (var _uow = new UCAS_WebSync_AdminTool_UOF())
        {
            try
            {
                List<PeopleEntity> peopleEntity = null ;

                int? personCode = _uow.Web_SyncMatchesRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.SUBMISSION_ID == "28105").Select(y => y.PERSON_CODE).FirstOrDefault() ;

                using(var _fes_uow = new FES_UOF())
                {
                    peopleEntity = _fes_uow.PeopleRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.PERSON_CODE == personCode).ToList();
                    var t = "d";
                }

               WebSyncDetailObject = (from esm in _uow.Web_SyncMatchesRepository.GetAll()
                                      join lup in (_uow.Web_LookupsRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.RV_DOMAIN == "match_method")) on esm.MATCH_METHOD equals lup.LOOKUP_KEY
                                      where esm.SUBMISSION_ID == "28105"
                                      select new WebSyncDetailEntity {WebSyncMatch = esm, WebLookups = lup, People = peopleEntity }).ToList();

                //throw error here!
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
            }
        }

            return null;
    }
```

[image]

I want final result in WebSyncDetailEntity object

### 2nd error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer; loop through list and add object to existing list object where matches condition

```
 public class WebSyncDetailEntity
{
    public Web_SyncMatchesEntity WebSyncMatch { get; set; }

    public Web_LookupsEntity WebLookups { get; set; }

    public PeopleEntity People { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
 private List<WebSyncDetailEntity> ProcessGetWebSyncDetail()
    {
        List<WebSyncDetailEntity> WebSyncDetailObject = null;

        using (var _uow = new UCAS_WebSync_AdminTool_UOF())
        {
            try
            {
                List<PeopleEntity> peopleEntity = null ;

                int? personCode = _uow.Web_SyncMatchesRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.SUBMISSION_ID == "28105").Select(y => y.PERSON_CODE).FirstOrDefault() ;

                using(var _fes_uow = new FES_UOF())
                {
                    peopleEntity = _fes_uow.PeopleRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.PERSON_CODE == personCode).ToList();
                }

                WebSyncDetailObject = (from esm in _uow.Web_SyncMatchesRepository.GetAll()
                                         join lup in (_uow.Web_LookupsRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.RV_DOMAIN == "match_method")) on esm.MATCH_METHOD equals lup.LOOKUP_KEY
                                         where esm.SUBMISSION_ID == "28105"
                                         select new WebSyncDetailEntity { WebSyncMatch = esm, WebLookups = lup }).ToList();

                  int index = 0;
                  foreach(var item in WebSyncDetailObject)
                  {
                      WebSyncDetailObject[index].People = peopleEntity.Where(x => x.PERSON_CODE == WebSyncDetailObject[index].WebSyncMatch.PERSON_CODE).FirstOrDefault();
                      index++;
                  }
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
            }
        }
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you're getting an exception here is that it's trying to include `peopleEntity` in the query being sent to the database.  This won't work, as complex datatypes aren't supported in queries.

A simple fix would be to leave the `People` field null when you first create the `WebSyncDetailObject` in the query, then set it to `peopleEntity` on the next line.

Comment: I have done first part but then how I set it to peopleEntity on the next line??

Comment: Well it's going to be the same for every `WebSyncDetailEntity` in `WebSyncDetailObject` so you could do a foreach loop and set the property for each one.  Kosala's answer seems like a neater way of doing it though tbh!

Comment: Also, why do you want a list of `WebSyncDetailEntity` objects which all point back to the same `People` object?  Would it be better to have an object which has a list of `WebSyncDetailEntity`, and a single reference to the relevant `People` object?

Comment: ideally be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.

```
var resultsFromDb = (from esm in _uow.Web_SyncMatchesRepository.GetAll()
                                      join lup in (_uow.Web_LookupsRepository.GetAll().Where(a => a.RV_DOMAIN == "match_method")) on esm.MATCH_METHOD equals lup.LOOKUP_KEY
                                      where esm.SUBMISSION_ID == "28105" select new {esm = esm, lup = lup, peopleEntity = peopleEntity}).ToList(); // Here we break the linq to sql query

// Then run a select query on the above collection to get what we want.  
WebSyncDetailObject  = resultsFromDb.Select(r => new WebSyncDetailEntity {WebSyncMatch = r.esm, WebLookups = r.lup, People = r.peopleEntity }).ToList();
```

Comment: var resultsFromDb  says A Query Body Must end with a select clause  or a group clause ... throw error

Comment: I missed that part. Fixed. Try now.

Comment: throw error, I have already tried this, using peopleEntity = peopleEntity using in first LINQ query conflict when ToList() error: only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Comment: Which one is throwing the error? 1st query or the 2nd query?

Comment: check screen shot of error under 2nd error, I have updated my question

Comment: So the actual problem is with the "people" collection. Have you tried adding "ToList" next to "peopleEntity" like `peopleEntity = peopleEntity.ToList()}` ?

Comment: I have update my class object model and remove list from People ...  public class WebSyncDetailEntity
    {
        public Web_SyncMatchesEntity WebSyncMatch { get; set; }

        public Web_LookupsEntity WebLookups { get; set; }

        public PeopleEntity People { get; set; }
    } .... still getting same error ...

Comment: Have you tried again after removing "peopleEntity" from the first query? You may have to run another query to get people.

Comment: I have found the solution, refer to my answer